# Universal Image Loader Showing Wrong Images for Wrong Items in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-drawable, universal-image-loader, image-loading

I am a beginner in android coding...And I stumbled On this problem where UIL is showing wrong images for wrong items in a list view Here is my adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl.WeakMemoryCache;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;


public class ClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
   public final String[] CarI;



public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView carTitle;

    ImageView carImage;



}

public ClassAdapter(Context context, String[] mclaren, String[] CarI) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_listview, mclaren);
    this.CarI = CarI;


}
public ViewHolder holder;



public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SetupImageLoader();
    final View result;




    String singleCar = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mcInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = mcInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.carImage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.carTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);

        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).build();


    try {
        imageLoader.displayImage(CarI[position], holder.carImage, options);


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    holder.carTitle.setText(singleCar);

    return convertView;

}

public void SetupImageLoader() {
    // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();


    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
 }



}
```

Also Here is the activity which has the list view:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Honda extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_honda);
    String honda[]= {"Accord","Civic", "Civic Si", "Civic Type R","Clarity","CR-V","Fit","HR-V","Insight","Odyssey","Pilot","Ridgeline","Acura ILX","Acura MDX","Acura NSX","Acura RDX","Acura RLX","Acura TLX"};
    final String hondaI[] = {
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.accord,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.civic,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.civicsi,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.civictyper,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.clarity,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.crv,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.fit,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.hrv,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.insight,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.odyssey,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.hopilot,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.hridgeline,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.a124,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.mdx,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.nsx,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.rdx,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.a123,
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.tlx,
    };
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ListAdapter customAdapter = new ClassAdapter(this, honda, hondaI);
    list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
      }
    }
```

and here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".Honda">

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list5"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="643dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is important to mention that i added multiple list views that have to load images from the drawable folder, and these images are the ones displaying in wrong order or even sometimes in the wrong list!

Comment: Images are displaying in wrong list or the names of cars?

Comment: The issue is not with Image loader, but with ListView. Use RecyclerView instead. But you can also remove check for convertView and each time inflate new view. This should help

Comment: try using the singleCar variable when assigning the string to the imageView loader